# Can't get environment variable in groovy post build plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have done it many times before but for some reason, it stoped working.

I try to post a Machine IP in groovy post script as the [plugin wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) suggesting.

for some reason, I'm getting **"null"** even though I can see that the parameter I want to use is defined as an environment variable.

This is my groovy:

```
manager.addShortText("${manager.build.buildVariables.get('Master_Machine_IP')}")
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you try to ```manager.addShortText("v${manager.build.buildVariables.get('Master_Machine_IP')}")```

Comment: v$ will just add v in the begging of the output  -(vnull)